# How to get the list of tables to show the correct page number of a longtable

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, longtable

When you put a `caption` beneath a `longtable`, how can you get the list of tables to show the correct page number (i.e. the page where the table begins, rather than where it ends)?

---

#### Example

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

#### Code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array,arydshln,xcolor,enumitem}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\newcommand\colbox[2]{\colorbox{#1}{\makebox[60pt]{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{30pt}%
\textcolor{white}{\large#2}}}}
\definecolor{RED}{HTML}{D43F3A}
\definecolor{ORA}{HTML}{EE9336}
\definecolor{YEL}{HTML}{FDC431}
\definecolor{GRE}{HTML}{3FAE49}
\definecolor{BLU}{HTML}{0071B9}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection - Table Starts Here}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\caption{Table One}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\scriptsize\centering\noindent
\begin{longtable}{crl}
\toprule                                                                %%
Column A & Column B & Column C                                                 \\
\midrule                                                                %%
\endhead

%\caption{Table One}
\toprule                                                                %%
Column A & Column B & Column C                                                 \\
\midrule                                                                %%
%\caption{Table One}
\endfirsthead
\hdashline

\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{RED}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{ORA}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{YEL}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{GRE}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\colorbox{BLU}{\parbox{5em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{AAAAA}}} & BBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC \\\hdashline
\bottomrule                                                             %%
\caption{Table One}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subsection{Second Subsection - Table Ends Here}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Follow the typographical tradition: table captions, contrary to figure captions, are *above* tables (the reason for this is precisely multipage tables). For `longtable` , this means caption has to be before `\endfirsthead`.

Comment: @Bernard I want to change a single digit on a single page, not refactor the entire document.

Comment: That's not such a big change… And your layout, from a typographical point of view, won't be faulty. Now, you also can modify manually the file shet this information is contained, but you'll have to modify  it just before the last compilation.